# Does mongodb sharded collection's performance deteriorate as the number of shards grow?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-indexes, horizontal-scaling

At what number of shards do sharded collections begin to have a negative impact on the performances of read queries? Hundreds? Thousands? what is the rule of thumb?

Comment: Would you have access to thousands of servers? If not, why do you ask?

Comment: But I am not trying to use my own servers. I will be using MongoDB atlas service and hence their servers.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cluster-additional-settings/ "*Your cluster can have between 1 and 50 shards, inclusive.*"